# Live-refresh places answers above paginator

Tags: bug, answers, live-refresh, pagination

When viewing a question with enough answers to add a pagination control, if a new answer arrives and the “1 new answer” banner appears, clicking the banner adds the answer *above* the paginator, when really the paginator should stay at the top at all times:

[image: The paginator should be at the top, not after an answer.]